# Neo4j Structure for GPS coordinates log

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm using neo4j for a, let's call it, social network where users will have the ability to log their position during workouts (think Runkeeper and Strava).

I'm thinking about how I want to save the coordinates.
Is it a good idea to have it like `node(user)-has->node(workouts)<-is a-node(workout)-start->node(coord)-next->node(coord)-next->....` i.e. a linked list with coordinates for every workout?

I will never query the db for individual points, the workout will always be retrieved as a whole.

Is it a better way to solve this?

I can image that a graph db isn't the ideal db to store this type of data, but I don't want to add the complexity of adding another db right now.

Can someone give me any insight on this?

Comment: Looking at answers in other neo4j questions, maybe @PeterNeubauer can give some insight?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you store it as:

```
user --has--> workout --positionedAt--> coord
```

This design feels more natural to me as the linked list design you mentioned in your question just produces a really deep traversal which might be annoying to query. In this way you can easily find all the coordinates for a particular workout by simply iterating edges on the `workout` vertex.  I would recommend storing a datetime stamp on the `positionedAt` edge so that you can sort your coordinates easily.

The downside is that depending on how many `coord` vertices you intend to have you might end up with some fat `workout` vertices, but that may not really affect your use case.  I can't think of a workout that would generate something like 100000 coordinates (and hence 100000 edges), but perhaps you can.  If so, I suppose I could amend my answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @stephen! Imagine taking a coord every 5 seconds, this race http://runkeeper.com/user/oskarhane/activity/153751368 would have ≈ 20000 points. Am I gettings this right that you are connecting every `coord` via `positionedAt` directly to the `workout`? And every new `workout` directly via `has` to the user? Will there be a problem if every user has like 1000 `workouts` or is it still fast?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "fast" and the context of how you intend to query it.  If you need to find the average workout time, by by traversing from the `user` to every single `workout` to get the start/end time from the `coord` vertices, that's a painful traversal.  In such a case it might be smart to store the start/end/elapsed time on the `workout` itself.  With graphs, performance depends a lot on how much of the graph you have to touch to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: You should also know the strengths and weaknesses of the various graph databases out there before making a choice on which is best for your use case.  Checkout http://tinkerpop.com for a way to try out many different graphs (including Neo4j) before making your choice.